# Will the warning bar go away

Tags: javascript, html, activex

I am starting to build a site with HTML and JavasSript as well as embedded YouTube videos.

When I load the site on ie8 I get a warning saying that ie stoped the files that could access my computer. I don't really mind pressing it to actually load my page but when I put it on my web hoster, will that message go away?

Thanks,
Luck

Comment: my html document, it stoped it from loading properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing that this is the message that you're seeing:

[image]

The warning appears when a page attempts to load a local, external JavaScript file. Once the page is being served by HTTP you will not see this warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mark of the web: `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->` to prevent the warning bar. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28VS.85%29.aspx